# I have upgraded the spring boot to 2.6.6 and application is up while I'm trying to hit the end point in getting 404 error

Tags: spring-boot, localhost, http-status-code-404, endpoint

I have removed the component scan as I was getting unsatisfieddependency exception can somebody please let me know what am i missing

I tried to change @controller to @restcontroller

Comment: W need code to answer.

Comment: Share your code